# Matching column values from two different dataframes and pairing observations

Tags: python, pandas

So I have no idea how to this, and looking around for half a day I have not found my solution.

My data looks something like this

```
import pandas as pd

df1 = pd.DataFrame(
    [['132','233','472','098'], ['482','214','980',''], ['107','','',''], 
    ['571','498','',''],], columns=["p1", "p2", "p3", "p4"])
df2 = pd.DataFrame(['532','233','980','132', '298'], columns=["p"])
```

```
df1
    p1      p2      p3
0   132     233     472
1   482     214     980
2   107         
3   571     498     

df2
    p
0   532
1   233
2   980
3   132
4   298
```

I wish to match the values in the p column with any one of the values in the p{1-3} columns, and create a new column which contains the matched string.

So in this instance my desired output is

```
df_output

    p1      p2      p3    matched_p 
0   132     233     472   233
1   482     214     980   980
2   107         
3   571     498
```

I tried the following

```
filter1 = df1['p1'].isin(df2['p'])
filter2 = df1['p2'].isin(df2['p'])
filter3 = df1['p3'].isin(df2['p'])
df1['matched_p'] = df2['p'][filter1 | filter2 | filter3]
```

however, this gave me non-sensical results.

Any ideas on how to approach this problem?

Comment: what about when 2 columns match from the same row? first row matches 2 values

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this. Using [`df.isin`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.isin.html) and [`df.where`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.where.html) with [`df.max`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.max.html) over axis 1.

```
df1 = df1.replace('',np.nan).astype(float) # to convert everything to float.
df2 = df2.astype(float) #to convert everything to float.
m = df1.isin(df2['p'].to_numpy())
df1['matched_values'] = df1.where(m,0).max(1)
df1

      p1     p2     p3    p4  matched_values
0  132.0  233.0  472.0  98.0           233.0
1  482.0  214.0  980.0   NaN           980.0
2  107.0    NaN    NaN   NaN             NaN
3  571.0  498.0    NaN   NaN             NaN
```

If you don't want to convert your dtypes to `float`.

Inspired from [@Erfan's](https://stackoverflow.com/a/62180368/12416453) solution. I combined our approaches.

```
df1['matched'] = (df1.where(
                  df1.isin(df2['p'].to_numpy()),'').
                  add(',').sum(1).str.strip(','))
```

Comment: The combined approach worked like a charm thank you!

Answer (score 2):

We can use `stack` and `unstack` here with `isin` and some string manipulation. This will also account for multiple matches:

```
d1 = df1.stack()
d1 = d1.where(d1.isin(df2['p'])).unstack().fillna('')
d1 = d1.add(',').sum(axis=1).str.strip(',')

df1['matched_p'] = d1

    p1   p2   p3   p4 matched_p
0  132  233  472  098   132,233
1  482  214  980            980
2  107                         
3  571  498
```

Comment: Alternate solution `df1['match_p'] = df1.where(df1.isin(df2['p'].values),'').add(',').sum(1).str.strip(',')`

Comment: `values` shouldnt be used since a long time, see big warning box in [docs](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.values.html)

Comment: Learnt something new. Thanks ;)

Comment: Still your solution is valid, but just replace `.values` with `.to_numpy()`

Comment: Thank you. I just combined our approaches :P

Comment: I added your answer link to my answer is it fine? And thanks learnt something new, I predominantly use `.values`. +1

Answer (score 0):

```
set1 = set(df2['p'])

df1['p'] = df1.apply(lambda x: {x['p1'], x['p2'], x['p3'], x['p4']}.intersection(set1), axis=1)
df1['p'] = df1['p'].map(lambda x: x.pop() if x else '')
```